# MySQL Left Join depending on Two Fields

Tags: mysql

Let's assume we have 2 tables:

First table: "members"

```
id    name
===========
10    Rooney

20    George

30    Hoytt

40    Percy
```

Second table: "interactions"

```
id    iType    mem1    mem2
===========================
5501   PRIVMSG   10    30

5502   NOTICE    20    40
```

And the result should be:

```
id    iType    mem1    mem2    mem1name    mem2name
==========================================
5501   PRIVMSG 10    30      Rooney     Hoyyt

5502   NOTICE  20    40      George     Percy
```

How can we achive this output table using a single MySQL query?

Thanks by now.

Comment: ..at least you should try something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use two joins and give them differen aliasses like this:

```
SELECT interactions.*,m1.name as 'mem1name',m2.name as 'mem2name'
FROM 
    interactions 
    LEFT JOIN members m1 ON (interactions.mem1 = m1.id) 
    LEFT JOIN members m2 ON (interactions.mem2 = m2.id)
```

Comment: minor syntax error. m2 table should be join with mem2 field and your m1 join is missing "=" sign. was gonna edit your post but changes are too small to be accepted :)

Comment: Thanks. Rectified my mistake. ;-)

Comment: that worked as expected, thank you. When it comes to performance issues, I guess this is the fastest and most proper way for a MySQL server, right?